# can't override symfony 5 exception templates

Tags: symfony, twig

I follow the Symfony current documentation to override exception templates :
[How to Customize Error Pages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#example-404-error-template)

In my AccesDeniedListener.php class i put :

```
 public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event, string $eventName = null): void
{
    $exception = $event->getThrowable();
    if (!$exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
        return;
    }

    // ... perform some action (e.g. logging)

    // optionally set the custom response
    $event->setResponse(new Response(null, 403));

    // or stop propagation (prevents the next exception listeners from being called)
    //$event->stopPropagation();
}
```

I already installed symfony/twig-pack

and in my templates folder i added Execption twigs :

[image]

Finally my new twigs are not applied

Comment: Are you sure u are in prod mode(`APP_ENV=prod`) ? Also Please edit your post and add the code of `error403.html.twig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application environment is set to prod you should get the custom error pages. If your application environment is set to dev, then you will still get the development error messages. To test your custom page in dev you can add the special route as explained in the guide you followed.

```
# config/routes/dev/framework.yaml
_errors:
    resource: '@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml'
    prefix:   /_error
```

With that config in dev, you should be able to access http://example.com/_error/403.